# compile souce code of android in cygwin

Tags: android

i have several problem:

1. if i modify   Email app ,if i can use cygwin to compile.if yes how to compile,if no  if i can compile in VMware Workstation with Ubuntu.
2. if i modify  framework resources,if i can use cygwin to compile.if yes how to compile,if no  if i can compile in VMware Workstation with Ubuntu.
3. how to combile  whole source code ,if i can use cygwin or VMware Workstation with Ubuntu

every one can give me some guide  or link  and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.)The email app almost certainly is just a java app like every other app. You don't need cygwin, you can make android apps on windows.

2.) What framework resources? You mean android source code? You'll have to cross compile it for whatever architecture your phone runs on. This is extremely non trivial, and probably not even possible in cygwin.